# How do I make two divs curve into each other?

Tags: html, css

As seen in the below image,

[image: attached image]

I have a bottom div where the top left and top right start curving in. The bottom div has a fixed height of 100px and a width of 100%.

**BOTTOM DIV**

```
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: white;
border-top-left-radius: ???px;
border-top-right-radius: ???px;
```

I also have a top div that is green that is supposed to to connect to the top left/right curve of the bottom div.

**TOP DIV**

```
width: ???;
height: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: ???px;
border-bottom-right-radius: ???px;
```

How do I make two divs curve into one another? The top div is not the same width as the bottom div (it's a few pixels shorter on each side) and I don't know how to make them dynamically link up.

Comment: Your approach doesn't seem right. This can be done with a large parent div with a border-radius and a child div at the top of the parent...? Any reason why it cant be done that way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a container with `overflow: hidden`, and also set `border-radius` on that container.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 115px; /* Top + bottom divs' heights */
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden; /* You should add this */
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
  
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  
  </div>
</div>
```